# How to get a table of users and their roles in .core mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

At first I have a table of users from `userManager` where I can search and sort by username. The original table is following  [microsoft .net tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-3.1)
but now I am trying join the role of each user from `roleManager`. Tried to look for other solution in stackoverflow but I couldn't implement them into my code below. How should I revise my code to get the result from user from `userManager` and role from `roleManager` in one table?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ListUsers(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? pageNumber, string name)
        {

            ViewData["NameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "userid" : "username";
            ViewData["DateSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
            var users = userManager.Users;

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                pageNumber = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                users = userManager.Users.Where(u => u.Name.Contains(searchString));
            }

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "userid":
                    users = users.OrderByDescending(s => s.UserName);
                    break;
                case "username":
                    users = users.OrderByDescending(s => s.Name);
                    break;
                case "Date":
                    users = users.OrderBy(s => s.BirthDate);
                    break;
                case "date_desc":
                    users = users.OrderByDescending(s => s.BirthDate);
                    break;
                default:
                    users = users.OrderBy(s => s.UserName);
                    break;
            }
            int pageSize = 50;
            return View(await PaginatedList<ApplicationUser>.CreateAsync(users.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
            //return View(await users.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
        }
```

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/list-of-users-with-roles-in-mvc-asp-net-identity/

Comment: what does your userManager model look like? Does it have a fk relation with roles?

Comment: Hi @LinkedListT, the userManager is defined by `private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;` , but in  `ApplicationUser` there is no Role field. In my database, there are `AspNetUsers`, `AspUserRoles` and `AspNetRoles` 3 three tables. Just hoping to see if there is a way to join these 3 tables together in order to get the list... Thanks.

Comment: Check this out. https://forums.asp.net/t/2083257.aspx?Get+a+table+with+all+users+and+their+roles After getting user, you can iterate through roles table and do a simple query to get role by username - or preferably userId.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In default ASP.NET Core Identity , the relationship between User and Role is many-to-many. And in EF Core ,you should represent a many-to-many relationship by including an entity class for the join table and mapping two separate one-to-many relationships.

For getting all users with their associated roles , this [comment on GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1361#issuecomment-348863959) seems to be the current solution for .Net Core . Here is a working demo :

*ApplicationUser*

```
public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser<string>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

}
```

*ApplicationRole*

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

*ApplicationUserRole*

```
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

*ApplicationDbContext*

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, IdentityUserClaim<string>,
ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>,
IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>(userRole =>
        {
            userRole.HasKey(ur => new { ur.UserId, ur.RoleId });

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId);

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.User)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);
        });
    }   
}
```

*Startup.cs*

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultUI()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

*Controller*

```
var users = _userManager.Users
            .Include(u=>u.UserRoles)
                .ThenInclude(ur=>ur.Role).AsNoTracking();
```

Microsoft doc on multi-level eager loading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#including-multiple-levels

*View*

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BirthDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @foreach (var userRole in item.UserRoles)
            {
                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(model=>userRole.Role.Name)&nbsp;</p>
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
```

*Result:*

[image]