# InvalidOperationException: a second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-8.0

I'm working on an application on .NET Core 8 which uses EF and authentication with individual accounts. I'm trying to display a set of users with their roles. I got the code from this page:

[The page I got the code from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65500957/how-to-display-a-list-of-users-with-roles-asp-net-core)

This is that code:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var users = _userManager.Users.Select(c => new UsersViewModel()
    {
        Username = c.UserName,
        Email = c.Email,
        Role = string.Join(",", _userManager.GetRolesAsync(c).Result.ToArray())
    }).ToList();

    return View(users);
}
```

To work with my application I have modified the code to:

```
public IList<User> Users { get; set; } = default!;

public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    IQueryable<User> users = _userManager.Users.Select(c => new User()
    {
        Username = c.UserName,
        Role = string.Join(",", _userManager.GetRolesAsync(c).Result.ToArray())
    });

    Users = await users.ToListAsync();
}
```

When I run this application, sometimes I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.

I assumed that it's caused by the `GetRolesAsync` method not having an await. And I added an await like this:

```
IQueryable<User> users = _userManager.Users.Select(c => new User()
{
    Username = c.UserName,
    Role = string.Join(",", await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(c).Result.ToArray())
});

Users = await users.ToListAsync();
```

Then I get the compile-time error:

> 'string[]' doesn't contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'string[]' could be found

Can someone explain to me how to correct this code? I tried a few other changes also but all of them have various compiler errors.

Comment: the await call to GetRolesAsync should be, (await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(c)).ToArray()

Comment: Then the code looks like this; 

IQueryable<User> users = _userManager.Users.Select(async c => new User()
{
    Username = c.UserName,
    Role = string.Join(",", (await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(c)).ToArray())
});

Then I get the compiler error Async lambda expression cannot be converted to expression trees.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39518163/using-async-await-inside-select-lambda this should help you

Comment: @Sharath N S Thanks for the link. I tried the code which is given as answers in it. The first answer doesn't work because the user instance you have to pass to the GetRolesAsync() method has to be the Microsoft inbuilt user kind. This answer passes the coder's custom user. The second answer doesn't work either. There're other ways of displaying a list of users and their roles I can find but they take up a lot of code. The way I'm trying is a lot less code so I'm looking for a way to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try following code which works.

```
        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            var users = new List<User>();

            var items = await _userManager.Users.ToListAsync();
            foreach (var c in items)
            {

                var result = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(c);
                users.Add(new User()
                {
                    Username = c.UserName,
                    Role = string.Join(",", result.ToArray())
                });
            }
            var final = users;
        }
```

Test
[image]