# EF creates new columns when trying to map properties to existing columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

So i am trying to follow the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59854153/3719277
where i want to map existing FK columns to new properties. But when running add-migration it wants to duplicate the existing columns in the database:

**Migration:**

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "RoleId1",
            table: "AspNetUserRoles",
            type: "nvarchar(450)",
            nullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "UserId1",
            table: "AspNetUserRoles",
            type: "nvarchar(450)",
            nullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_AspNetUserRoles_RoleId1",
            table: "AspNetUserRoles",
            column: "RoleId1");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_AspNetUserRoles_UserId1",
            table: "AspNetUserRoles",
            column: "UserId1");

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId1",
            table: "AspNetUserRoles",
            column: "RoleId1",
            principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId1",
            table: "AspNetUserRoles",
            column: "UserId1",
            principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
    }
```

ApplicationUserRole:

```
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public virtual EQUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }

}
```

ApplicationRole:

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

}
```

User:

```
public class EQUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
    public bool ReceiveMailUpdates { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
```

Changes to OnModelCreating:

```
public class EQAContext : IdentityDbContext<EQUser, ApplicationRole, string, IdentityUserClaim<string>,
    ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>, IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>(userRole =>
        {
            userRole.HasKey(ur => new { ur.UserId, ur.RoleId });

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId);

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.User)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);
        });
```

Startup add identity:

```
        services.AddIdentity<EQUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddUserStore<EQUserStore>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>() 
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<EQAContext>()
            .AddUserManager<EQUserManager>();
```

It seems that this has always been the way EF handles this, but how do i get around this, so that i don't loose the data that is already in use. Usually i just delete the Up code because it is trying to create a column with the existing name, but here it creates a column with a new name.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this happens when you haven't configured the whole project to use the new entity instead of the old one. You most likely need to provide the `ApplicationUserRole` in the generic type arguement in your `IdentityDbContext`

Comment: `IdentityUser` already has a `Roles` and foreign key. You've specified a duplicate FK, so you get duplicate columns. Do you really need to change the navigation property? The right answer will be somewhere in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @Shoejep i have updated my question to show that i have used all the new classes in the IdentityContext
JeremyLakeman: It doesn't have a navigational property on the IdentityUser class, hence the questing i linked to. My problem is that i don't want a new FK but bind the current FK to a new navigational property

Comment: @Chimera What about in `Startup.cs`? There's `AddIdentity` for e.g. that requires the new entities.

Comment: @Shoejep I believe so. I'll update the question with startup.

Comment: @Chimera It looks like you're specify `IdentityRole` but it should be `ApplicationRole`. You'll need to check your `EQUserManager` as well.